# "Ask Question" and "Top Questions" too close to each other on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, responsive-design

A recent change seems to have moved the "Ask Question" button and the "Top Questions" text closer to each other, and now they're touching. This seems wrong to me:

[image: screenshot of the button and text]

Could this please be fixed?

Comment: Good find, on it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for reporting! A fix has been merged and will go live in the next build.